# Chrome extension messing with background image

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

While developing an extension for chrome, I noticed that it messes with the size of the background image of Gmail.

My option to fix this is to search for this image or image element and change it's `background-size` attribute to `cover`.

Any idea where I can find this element to fix it? Or a suggestion to a a better fix please?

Comment: Since it is your extension that messes with the image, how about fixing it, so it doesn't ?

Comment: That's the thing. I've been brought on after the product has been through 3 rounds of development. This issue was just brought to my notice and I've been trying to figure out the css behind it for quite a while but to no avail.

Comment: Still it is not a good solution to just change its `background-size` to cover. How do you know it will solve the problem ? How do you know the same problem won't be caused on other pages as well ? Developing an extension that may break a page is not a good practice. You should try to find what breaks it (and then stop it from breaking it).